# How do I configure Windows Firewall to send mail with stmp.office365.com?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, windows-firewall

I have an application in my server (Windows Server 2012 Stanrdard x64) that sends mails with smtp.office365.com with port 587.

I authorized only input HTTP connections and I blocked all output connections except protocol TCP with port 587 but this doesn't work. The mails aren't sended.

What rules I have to configure in order that the mails are sended ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your DNS resolution is working correctly the only thing you need to provide is SMTP access to smtp.office365.com on port 587. Please go back over the documentation and come back with more specific questions.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. My DNS resolution didn't work.

So I add 3 rules in my firewall :
1) Outbound rule to allow traffic for SMTP : Procol = TCP | Port = 587
2) Outbound rule to allow traffic for DNS : Procol = TCP | Port Distant = 53
3) Outbound rule to allow traffic for DNS : Procol = UDP| Port Distant = 53

And it's OK